# Save a list in database and after display the list. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question and I don't have any idea how to search it or make it.
I have a db for a job portal. In job_requirments column when i add a new row I want to save a list and after display it.

Example:

1. 3 years experience.
2. etc.
3. etc.

How can i make to be like an array and display it with a foreach loop? Thx.

Comment: Expand on `etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alexey Mezenin i realy like your answer and appreciated,
But usually all huge use of implode and explode to perform this

Take a type `text` of the column in database

Make a comma seperated string of array of values like `implode(",",$arr);`

And then store it  into the database while you want it back simply get that column string and exactly opposite of implode do `explode(",",$arr);`
it will return you an array of your all saved values

Comment: this was the easiest way. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can keep an array as JSON in DB.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'job_requirments' => 'array',
];
```

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 1):

```
$blog = new blog();
$blog->title = $req->title;
$blog->description = $req->description;
$blog->user_id=$req->user_id;
$blog->save();
return response()->json($blog);
```